# Can anyone tell me what this tattoo means? Please and thanks 

Tags: translation, meaning

my husband of 12 years has this tattoo on his chest. He got it when he was a teen. He thought it meant danger but it looks different then anything we've seen online. Can someone please tell us what this means??

Thank you [image]

Comment: Your husband is dangerous? 三合会的?

Answer (score 2):

the character is [坎 u+574e](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%9D%8E)

the name of the trigram ☵, which represents water

ar the same time, it’s also the name of hexagram ䷜, which symbolises “numerous dangers” (象重重險難之義)

[https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=4519&q=1&word=坎](https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=4519&q=1&word=%E5%9D%8E)

for more, you need to read “the book of change” (易經) lah

have fun :)

btw, how come a teen can get a tattoo?

Comment: some places allow teenagers to get tattoos, with parental permission in the usa.  Although I think this is probably a case of the tattoo artist not checking to make sure it was an adult/ it being an older time period when no one cared about it as strictly.

Answer (score 1):

坎 can mean dangers, obstacles, or hurdles.

坎 is very often combined with 坷 to form the term 坎坷. 生命坎坷 is "a life with many obstacles," or simply "a tough life." 前景坎坷 is "the future has many obstacles."